# Reading Dogbone (Magnus 3) sensor tags with Zebra RFD8500

Tags: tags, sensors, rfid

I'am trying to read the new sensor tags Dogbone, (with Magnus S3 IC) but I don't have luck. 
I'am using Zebra RFD8500 and programming with the Zebra SDK for Android.
I want to read the RSSI or the temperature values, but it seems the problem is with the Select command.

In either case, it is a two step procedure : 1) select command to match a specific tag pattern in a specific pointer address at the MEMORY_USER_BANK. Then the IC detect that have to store
the solicited value in a specific address at the MEMORY_RESERVED_BANK and 2) read the value, from the specific address at the MEMORY_RESERVED_BANK.
For the Select command (C1G2)  I tried with Access-filters and Pre-Filters, but although the tag is matched, the IC doesn't store a value in the RESERVED Bank.

Somebody knows if Zebra APIs support the reading of this newers tags ? Or suggest me any other test?
Thanks a lot for your help
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to read the RSSI value with EPC Gen2 tags, so if the tag you're referring to supports this standard it should work. 
Try downloading the Zebra RFID sample app > Perform inventory > If the tag is found it should display the RSSI. The sample app code can be found [here](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/demo/123rfid-mobile.html)
As for the temperature values try reading the USER memory in the sample app as well to see if you can get it.

Comment: Hi, thanks to answer me. I did some testings with the demo app, it's great. I can get the RSSI value that the reader see, as you suggest, but I want to get the on-chip RSSI saved at the tag. In the case of the temperature, for Magnus S3 to enable the temperature IC, I have to make first  a Select (EPC C1G2) of the user bank, with an empty mask, and I can't set it through the API, it don't accept 0bit mask.  Thanks for any other suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the SLS smartSLED; it has built-in functionality for the Magnus (Axzon) chip family (both S2 and S3).

Comment: https://www.atlasrfidstore.com/sls-rfid-smartsled-handheld-rfid-reader/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).